# Creating Markers with FSCollection

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, foreach, meteor

so i create markers when a new document get inserted on the FSCollection like this.

i have this find variable.

```
cordenadasClientes = Clientes.find({}, {fields:{'metadata.latCliente': 1,'metadata.longCliente':
```

follow by this eachFunction.

```
var count = 0,
markers = [],
marker;
   cordenadasClientes.forEach(function(){
     var latitudCliente = cordenadasClientes[count].metadata.latCliente;
     var longitudCliente = cordenadasClientes[count].metadata.longCliente;
     var nombreCliente = cordenadasClientes[count].metadata.nombreCliente;
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudCliente ,longitudCliente),
        map: map,
       title: nombreCliente,
        icon :'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_yellow.png',
      })
     count++;  
     markers.push(marker);
    })
```

And its work pretty find, every time i create some document on **Clientes** Collection, a marker its inserted, so also have this **markers array**, so every time a new marker its created **markers.push(marker);** its execute, and thats woork nice to, but now im trying to do this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function() {
map.setZoom(8);
```

});

but dont work, so im trying to see how my **markers** array looks like so make this other function;

```
     function arrayMarkers(element,index,array){
   console.log(markers);
```

}

and calling that **arrayMarkers** function like this;

```
[markers].forEach(arrayMarkers);
```

and getting this Console.log;

```
im the index : 0 and the object [object Object],[object Object]
```

So i want to create markers sotring on a array and after using that markers on a eventListener, what im doing wrong?, seems to like event listener just work on 1 marker

**example**
i have 2 markers, so when i click on 1 marker its zoom perfectly, but when i click on the second marker its soom to the first marker

this is how my **markers** array looks;
[On, On]>
0: on
1: on

like if im nesting array on an array

and if i use

```
function arrayMarkers(element,index,array){
       console.log(array);
}
```

i got this

```
[Array[2]]
>
0: Array[2]
>
0: On
1: On
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done By Creating this function

```
  //Added nombreCliente as parameter
    function     myInfoWindow(marker2,map,nombreCliente,telefonoCliente,ubicacionCliente,facebookCliente){
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
 for(var i=0;i<cordenadasClientes.length;i++){
  infoWindow.setContent( "Informacion Cliente : <br/>" + "Dale Pa: " + nombreCliente +  "<br/> Telefononos: " + telefonoCliente + "<br/>  Ubicado en: " + ubicacionCliente + "<br/> No olvides Pasarte Pa' su Facebook: ' " + '<a href="#' + facebookCliente + '">' );
infoWindow.open(map, marker2);
}});
}
```

And calling it just before **markers.push**

```
myInfoWindow(marker2,map,nombreCliente,telefonoCliente,ubicacionCliente,facebookCliente);
```